# Apache Zeppelin gives java.io.FileNotFoundException despite file being present in the location

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I am trying to create a very simple Zeppelin Notebook, which reads a csv file and does analysis on the file. However, I am running into a very weird error. Despite the file being shown in `ls` command, when I am trying to read it as `read.csv`, I am getting `java.io.FileNotFoundException`.

`ls` command shows `bank.csv` file (4th from top)
[image]

But getting exception when trying to read the file.
[image]

Comment: This link https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/In-Zeppelin-loading-a-simple-TextFile-where-do-I-put-a-file/td-p/173913 might helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### In a local / standalone Zeppelin installation...

There is a good chance that, by default, your Zeppelin notebook (and the underlying Spark stack) is configured to look in HDFS for relative file paths.

Therefore, you probably need to use an absolute file path, mentionning that you are working on your file system.

```
data = spark.csv.read("file:///data/your_path/banks.csv")
```

### In a cluster Zeppelin installation

If your notebook connects to a Spark installed cluster, then accessing local filesystem is not a good idea (you'd have to manually deploy files to everynode in the cluster, keep them in sync...)... Well that's why HDFS is made for.

So your best bet would be to take advantage of it. Put your file somewhere in your HDFS storage, then load it from spark over hdfs.

In your shell :

```
hdfs dfs -put /file_system_path/banks.csv "/user/zeppelin/banks.csv"
```

Please note that the actual path where your HDFS files can be put will vary based on your cluster installation.

Then Spark should be able to load it :

```
spark.csv.read("/user/zeppelin/banks.csv")
```

Of course, there are other ways than HDFS to do this. Spark can connect to S3, for instance, and if that suits you better than HDSF, this is a possibility to (`read("s3a://...")`)

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I am still getting the same error. I used `df = spark.read.csv("file:///zeppelin/bank.csv")` but still getting `java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/zeppelin/bank.csv does not exist`

Comment: I have used `mmlspark` helm chart to install Zeppelin on my Kubernetes cluster. https://github.com/Azure/mmlspark/tree/master/tools/helm/zepplin

Not sure if this Dockerfile is missing some crucial configurations.

Comment: I have edited for a typical cluster more. Your use of the `%sh` made me think you were working locally but if you're deploying to a k8s cluster, then probably not!

Comment: Hey it makes sense actually. I realised that same path has to be there on local file system of my spark drive, spark workers, zeppelin etc. I am trying to configure `s3` and use that as my file source. Thanks a lot for taking time to answer the question though.

Answer (score 0):

For people who come via same route, i.e install the stack using Helm on Kubernetes, and try to use a local file, which is present on Zeppelin Pod, that is a **bad bad** idea. You might end up wasting couple of hours trying to dig into internet and feeling stupid.

Basically, it will not work by design. All components will try and locate the file at the given specified path, but they won't find it, since it is only present on Zeppelin Pod or Container. The easiest approach, which I find is, to use AWS S3, but YMMV.

Need to export AWS Access key as environment variable on all components.

```
- name: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
  value: {{ .Values.Global.Aws.Key }}
- name: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
  value: {{ .Values.Global.Aws.Secret }}
```

And then use `spark.read.csv('s3a://YOUR_BUCKET_PATH/file.csv')` like a breeze.

Although **NOT** tested, but a similar approach without HDFS could be

1. Create a `PersistentVolumeClaim`
2. Mount that on same path on all the pods, i.e Spark Driver, Spark Worker, Zeppelin and put all files in the same mounted volume
3. Provide the absolute file path in the mounted volume using `file:///` directive

But again, this is a bad idea, since a Persistent Volume can not be mounted on more than 1 worker node. Just a Caveat to keep in mind.